# Django: Error 404 while trying to upload images on ImageField forms

Tags: python, django, webserver, python-imaging-library

I created a model with an ImageField and setup the media storage of Django to store files on Google Cloud. Everything seems to work fine locally, and I can create a new object from the cPanel and upload an image that successfully goes to Google Cloud bucket.
The problem showed up when I uploaded the project to my webserver. When I try to create an object there, it throws an 404 error page not found on POST Request. It only happens when I try to create objects for this model. 
Is it possible that something in the webserver host, blocks the POST requests that contain a file?

Thinks I've checked:

- Django version 3.0.6
- Pillow version 7.2.0
- Python version > 3.5
- Webserver successfully speaks with Google Cloud Bucket

EDIT: 
Here is some code for better understanding.

```
    @deconstructible
    class PathAndRename(object):
    
        def __init__(self, sub_path):
            self.path = sub_path
    
        def __call__(self, instance, filename):
            ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
            # set filename as random string
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
            print(filename)
            # return the whole path to the file
            return os.path.join(self.path, filename)
    
    path_and_rename = PathAndRename('media/upload/blogposts')
    
    STATUS = (
        (0,"Draft"),
        (1,"Publish")
    )
    class BlogPost(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
        content = models.TextField()
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
        upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename, default="test.png", null=True)
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_on']
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

And in the settings.py

```
# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

Comment: Please add the code of the model so we can help you

Comment: i edited the post with some code

Comment: Please add also the setting.py part where you set the MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: Ok, I also added the default file storage.